# MySQL Stored Procedure and only update if certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

The stored procedure is goin to take in a firstName, lastName, currentPostalCode and newPostalCode as arguements. I want to update the postalCode column only if there is one person with the given firstName, lastName and currentPostalCode.

How is this done? Do you use sub queries or the MySQL IF() or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to say you will only do the update if there is _exactly one_ matching row, whereby 2 matching rows would _not_ be updated?

Comment: Yeah and also throw an error and exit the query if there is not 1 matching row.

Comment: for that you need some branch logic. See the addition below, which assigns the number of matching rows to a variable and executes the UPDATE if exactly one matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any fancy conditional logic to perform this action, just a regular `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` clause will do it. If no rows is matched by the `WHERE` clause, no update takes place.

```
/* Update the records with matching name & postcode */
UPDATE  yourtable
  SET postalCode = 'newPostalCode'
WHERE
  /* If all 3 conditions don't match, nothing gets updated */
  firstName = 'firstName'
  AND lastName = 'lastName'
  AND postalCode = 'oldPostalCode'
```

As a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePostalCode (
  IN in_firstName VARCHAR(64),
  IN in_lastName VARCHAR(64),
  IN in_oldPostalCode VARCHAR(16),
  IN in_newPostalCode VARCHAR(16)
)
BEGIN
  UPDATE yourtable 
  SET
    postalCode = in_newPostalCode 
  WHERE 
    lastName = in_lastName 
    AND firstName = in_firstName 
    AND postalCode = in_oldPostalCode;
END
```

#### Addendum: If you really only want to do this if there is exactly one match...

To update only in the event of exactly one matching row (not 2 or more), you can still use a plain update statement, with an additional subquery in the `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE  yourtable
  SET postalCode = 'newPostalCode'
WHERE
  /* If all 3 conditions don't match, nothing gets updated */
  firstName = 'firstName'
  AND lastName = 'lastName'
  AND postalCode = 'oldPostalCode'
  /* Result of count subquery = 1 */
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS matched 
    FROM yourtable 
    WHERE firstName = 'firstName' AND lastName = 'lastName' AND postalCode = 'oldPostalCode'
  ) = 1
```

#### Addendum 2 To exit with error if there is not exactly one match:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePostalCode (
  IN in_firstName VARCHAR(64),
  IN in_lastName VARCHAR(64),
  IN in_oldPostalCode VARCHAR(16),
  IN in_newPostalCode VARCHAR(16)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE num_matched INT;
  SET num_matched = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE firstName = 'firstName' AND lastName = 'lastName' AND postalCode = 'oldPostalCode');

  IF (num_matched <> 1) THEN 
     /* Trigger an error and exit */
     LEAVE updatePostalCode
  END IF

  /* Perform the UPDATE statement */
END
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run my query it says syntax error, unexpected LEAVE_SYM. Any ideas? Is there something wrong with the IF() code maybe?